# How would you give the user the option to exit the program after answering 4 consecutive questions correctly?

Tags: java, terminate

I'm attempting to give the user the option to exit the program after he/she gets 4 multiplication questions correct. If he/she chooses to continue, I have to give him/her another chance to exit each time. I hope that makes sense.. My posted code works but I have a feeling that I will have to change some things in order to give user the option to terminate.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom; //program will use random numbers
import java.util.Scanner; //program will need user input

public class RandomMultiplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(true)//continues to play game
        {
            question();
        }
    }

    public static void question()
    {
        boolean repeat = false;
        SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
        //pick random numbers (1-9) for multiplication scenario
        int number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10); //first number
        int number2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10); //second number

        while(!repeat)
        {
            int responseCode = randomNumbers.nextInt(4);
            if(multiplicationProblem(number1,number2))
            {
                switch(responseCode)
                {
                case 0: System.out.println("Very Good!");
                    break;
                case 1: System.out.println("Excellent!");
                    break;
                case 2: System.out.println("Keep up the good work!");
                    break;
                case 3: System.out.println("Nice work!");
                    break;
                }//ends switch
                repeat = true; //stops repeating the same question
            }//end if statement
            else
            {
                responseCode = randomNumbers.nextInt(4);
                switch(responseCode)
                {
                case 0: System.out.println("No. Please try again!");
                    break;
                case 1: System.out.println("Wrong, Try once more!");
                    break;
                case 2: System.out.println("Don't give up!");
                    break;
                case 3: System.out.println("No. Keep trying!");
                    break;
                }//ends switch

            }//ends else condition

        }//ends while loop
    }

    public static boolean multiplicationProblem(int number1, int number2)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInputAnswer;
        int correctCounter = 0;

        System.out.printf("How much is %d times %d?", number1, number2);
        userInputAnswer = input.nextInt();
        if (userInputAnswer == number1 * number2)
        {
            return true;
        }       
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I apologize.. I thought I input my code correctly

Comment: Side note: Don't repeatedly create `Random` classes, just create one and then get numbers from it, and avoid `SecureRandom` unless you need it for cryptography, since it can block for no useful reason.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. Thanks